# how to restrict making http calls from aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am creating application which takes `nodejs` code from the user, and I am creating lambda function on the fly using that code.

eg: The code can be

```
var http = require('http');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  console.log('start request to ' + event.url)
  http.get('http://##someapi', function(res) {
    console.log("Any Response : " + res.statusCode);
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Error from API : " + e.message);
  });

  console.log('end request to ' + event.url)
  context.done(null);
}
```

But some how I want to restrict http/https calls to be made from that code , as I don't have control on what code will passed by the user.

So is there any way to restrict that, like some sort of ROLE or POLICY or any configuration to achieve that?

I am able to restrict DynamoDB access by specifying Policy in Role. So I have control over db access but not http calls.

Comment: @elssar Thanks for editing :)

Comment: The safest way would be to run the code in a sandbox. There are a few sandbox packages available on npm - https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=sandbox

Comment: @elssar : sandbox Looks good option.. but  i am not sure from sandbox , is it allowed to access/invoke aws resources ? like DynamoDB , other lambda function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply prepend the user's code with the following:

```
(function(){
  function onlyAWS (module) {
    var isAWS = /amazonaws.com$/i
    var orig = module.request
    module.request = function restrictedRequest (opts, done) {
      if (typeof opts === 'string') opts = require('url').parse(opts)
      if (isAWS.test(opts.host || opts.hostname)) {
        return orig.call(module, opts, done)
      } else {
        throw new Error('No HTTP requests allowed')
      }
    }
  }

  onlyAWS(require('http'))
  onlyAWS(require('https'))
})()
```

Comment: Not able to understand the solution .. can you please add more information

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be, putting these lambdas in a VPC with restricted Outbound access.

Comment: Yes , i have that in mind. its there in lambda configuration it self. In question i have only mentioned for http lib for simplicity. actually i wanted to restrict all 3rd libraries to load in lambda.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like funny solution but I found simple solution to my problem. I am adding below code along with code entered by User.

```
var require = function(){
    return "You are not allowed to do this operation";
}
```

Now if used user tries to include any 3rd party library like **required('http')** , then it will not allow to instantiate http lib in the node code.

using this solution I am able to block loading all 3rd party library which i don't want User to use in AWS lambda function.

I am still searching for proper solution instead of using that hack in code.